# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to push to the end of array a new value when `onSubmit` event is raised.
My code looks like this:

```
  accounts: Account[] = [];
  feeAccount: Account = new Account();

  onSubmit(f: FormsModule) {
    console.log('Fee account -> ' + this.feeAccount);
    this.accounts.push(this.feeAccount);
  }
```

The problem is that I'm getting an error: `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.` in spite of correct value logged just before it tries to push. What could be wrong here? I believe it is defined if it is logged correctly in the same method, or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Check that you're not accidentally mutating `accounts`, it appears to be correctly defined in the code above but if you're getting that error it suggests that it can't access `this.accounts` suggesting it's been changed to undefined from an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that, in somewhere in your code, you are assigning another type to `accounts` variable or mutating it acciendally which is obviously not **array** anymore

add `console.log` to debug `accounts` object on submit action

```
console.log(this.accounts);
console.log(typeof this.accounts);
```

will give you clear idea

Comment: The type wouldn't cause the error as JS doesn't actually have type checking when it's run. The error is caused b/c somewhere the value of `this.accounts` has been changed, not the type :)

Comment: I am not talking about type checking. but the type is actually changing from array to something else. Author is defined it as array but it is not anymore. it is something else like null, undefined, object or vs

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu it is undefined, but shouldn't it be undefined because now I'm trying to define it?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu sounds like a minor variance of semantics with value vs type.